# Getting automatic detection information from Airpods pro/max

Tags: ios, objective-c, airpods

Is it possible to get the information of automatic detection (when ear/head-phones are put/removed)?

If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the notification [`AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616493-routechangenotification). For full details (including how to properly respond to this notification), see [Responding to Audio Session Route Changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_route_changes).